# Some 2-byte Unicode characters appear as 2 characters in nano

Tags: fonts, nano, utf-8

I'm creating a web site in Russian. When I open HTML pages in nano on the remote server, some (but not all) of the Cyrillic characters appear as 2 characters:

For example, the phrase "Welcome" appears like this in the original file...

```
  Добро пожаловать
```

... and like this in nano in the Terminal window:

```
  �^�об�^�о пожалова�^��^�
```

If I copy these characters from nano and paste them anywhere (like here), they retain their strangeness. And yet these same characters appear correctly in the web page (perhaps due to the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag).

Is there some setting that I can apply to get nano to be prettily Cyrillic for me?

In case it's important, here's the shell I'm using:

```
# echo $0
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Is the encoding in your terminal emulator set to UTF-8?

Comment: And how would I discover that, or change it?

Comment: In gnome-terminal: _Terminal -> Set Character Encoding_

Comment: It says > Unicode (UTF-8)

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone else can help.